# Cloudformation template for creating ECS service stuck in CREATE_IN_PROGRESS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs

I am creating an AWS ECS service using Cloudformation.

Everything seems to complete successfully, I can see the instance being attached to the load-balancer, the load-balancer is declaring the instance as being healthy, and if I hit the load-balancer I am successfully taken to my running container.

Looking at the ECS control panel, I can see that the service has stabilised, and that everything is looking OK. I can also see that the container is stable, and is not being terminated/re-created.

However, the Cloudformation template never completes, it is stuck in `CREATE_IN_PROGRESS` until about 30-60 minutes later, when it rolls back claiming that the service did not stabilise. Looking at CloudTrail, I can see a number of `RegisterInstancesWithLoadBalancer` instantiated by `ecs-service-scheduler`, all with the same parameters i.e. same instance id and load-balancer. I am using standard IAM roles and permissions for ECS, so it should not be a permissions issue.

Anyone had a similar issue?

Comment: what fails in the cloud formation? do you have any failed events? Can you copy paste cloud formation event loG?

Comment: this typically means your instances/tasks haven't come up properly.

Comment: @Mircea It is the ECS service creation that fails with a message saying that service failed to stabilise. However looking in the ECS control panel there is a contradicting message saying that the service stabilised.

Comment: @tedder42 That is what I would suspect, however, if I disable rollback of the stack I can access my service/container/task successfully so it does seem like it is able to come up. In terms of instances, the cluster and instances is already up as they are created in a different template. I have also been able to verify that they work as expected.

Comment: There seems to be other people having the same issue: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=190250

Comment: @Anvar Did you ever managed to get this solved ?

Comment: @user2123288 No, in the end I resorted to writing a script that would invoke the CLI, and gave up on that particular Cloudformation template

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Your `AWS::ECS::Service` needs to register the full ARN for the `TaskDefinition` (Source: [See the answer from ChrisB@AWS on the AWS forums](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=690320#690320)).  The key thing is to set your `TaskDefinition` with the **full ARN, including revision**.  If you skip the revision (`:123` in the example below), the latest revision is used, but CloudFormation still goes out to lunch with "CREATE_IN_PROGRESS" for about an hour before failing.  Here's one way to do that:

```
"MyService": {
    "Type": "AWS::ECS::Service",
    "Properties": {
        "Cluster": { "Ref": "ECSClusterArn" },
        "DesiredCount": 1,
        "LoadBalancers": [
            {
                "ContainerName": "myContainer",
                "ContainerPort": "80",
                "LoadBalancerName": "MyELBName"
            }
        ],
        "Role": { "Ref": "EcsElbServiceRoleArn" },
        "TaskDefinition": {
            "Fn::Join": ["", ["arn:aws:ecs:", { "Ref": "AWS::Region" },
            ":", { "Ref": "AWS::AccountId" },
            ":task-definition/my-task-definition-name:123"]]}
        }
    }
}
```

Here's a nifty way to grab the latest revision of `MyTaskDefinition` via the aws cli and [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/):

```
aws ecs list-task-definitions --family-prefix MyTaskDefinition | jq --raw-output .taskDefinitionArns[0][-1:]
```

Comment: my command to retrieve the latest revision:
`aws ecs list-task-definitions --family-prefix dev-device-settings --sort DESC | jq --raw-output .taskDefinitionArns[0] | tr ':' '\n' | tail -1`

Comment: A much simpler way would be to use the `!Ref` function to return the ARN of your `AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition`. Building the ARN like that is very overly complicated. Look at the return values on this page: 

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ecs-taskdefinition.html

Answer (score 27):

I found another related scenario that will cause this and thought I'd put it here in case anyone else runs into it.  If you define a `TaskDefinition` with an Image that doesn't actually exist in its `ContainerDefinition` and then you try to run that `TaskDefinition` as a Service, you'll run into the same hang issue (or at least something that looks like the same issue).

**NOTE**: The example YAML chunks below were all in the same CloudFormation template

So as an example, I created this `Repository`:

```
MyRepository:
    Type: AWS::ECR::Repository
```

And then I created this `Cluster`:

```
MyCluster:
    Type: AWS::ECS::Cluster
```

And this `TaskDefinition` (abridged):

```
MyECSTaskDefinition:
    Type: AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition
    Properties:
        # ...
        ContainerDefinitions:
            # ...
              Image: !Join ["", [!Ref "AWS::AccountId", ".dkr.ecr.", !Ref "AWS::Region", ".amazonaws.com/", !Ref MyRepository, ":1"]]
            # ...
```

With those defined, I went to create a `Service` like this:

```
MyECSServiceDefinition:
    Type: AWS::ECS::Service
    Properties:
        Cluster: !Ref MyCluster
        DesiredCount: 2
        PlacementStrategies:
            - Type: spread
              Field: attribute:ecs.availability-zone
        TaskDefinition: !Ref MyECSTaskDefinition
```

Which all seemed sensible to me, but it turns out there two issues with this as written/deployed that caused it to hang.

1. The `DesiredCount` is set to 2 which means it will actually try to spin up the service and run it, not just define it.  If I set `DesiredCount` to 0, this works just fine.
2. The `Image` defined in `MyECSTaskDefinition` doesn't exist yet.  I made the repository as part of this template, but I didn't actually push anything to it.  So when the `MyECSServiceDefinition` tried to spin up the `DesiredCount` of 2 instances, it hung because the image wasn't actually available in the repository (because the repository literally just got created in the same template).

So, for now, the solution is to create the CloudFormation stack with a `DesiredCount` of 0 for the `Service`, upload the appropriate `Image` to the repository and then update the CloudFormation stack to scale up the service.  Or alternately, have a separate template that sets up core infrastructure like the repository, upload builds to that and then have a separate template to run that sets up the `Services` themselves.

Hope that helps anyone having this issue!

Comment: Also if the Task Definition doesn't have the appropriate `ExecutionRole` permissions, the service will hang in the `CREATING` state. I had this happen when I tried creating a `LogConfiguration`.

Comment: Also happens if image tag doesn't exist in the repository, e.g. perhaps a typo

Comment: "Hope that helps anyone having this issue!"
It indeed did! Thank you so much!

Comment: I have everything in one stack, set `DesiredCount` to 0 fixed ECS::Service `CREATE_IN_PROGRESS` take long time then build feil, thanks :)

Comment: An alternative if you just want to have one script that doesn't have to be updated is to take advantage of the long time CloudFormation hangs for (it is actually retrying and retrying to find the image when it hangs). This gives ample time to manually upload the image to ECR and then CloudFormation will find it pretty much as soon as it has been uploaded.

Answer (score 14):

No need to register the full ARN for the TaskDefinition, because when the logical ID of this resource is provided to the Ref intrinsic function, Ref returns the Amazon Resource Name (ARN).

In the following sample, the Ref function returns the ARN of the MyTaskDefinition task, such as arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:123456789012:task/1abf0f6d-a411-4033-b8eb-a4eed3ad252a.

{ "Ref": "MyTaskDefinition" }

Source http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ecs-taskdefinition.html

Comment: works great ... as long as the task definition is in the same stack.  Otherwise, the Fn::ImportValue is a nice way to do this across stacks.  
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-importvalue.html

Answer (score 8):

I think I had similar issue. 
Try looking at the "DesiredCount" property in the Service template. I think CloudFormation will indicate that the creation/update is still in progress until the Service reach that number of "DesiredCount" in your cluster.

Comment: The service is reporting as stabilised in the ECS UI, and both the desired count and the running count is set to 1. Hitting the container works as expected as well, and the ELB is reporting the instance correctly. It is like the notification just is not getting through to Cloudformation

Answer (score 6):

Anything that prevents the ECS Service definition from reaching the *Desired Count*. One example is missing permissions in the policies attached to the role used by the instances. Check the instances ECS agent logs (/var/log/ecs/ecs-agent.log.*timestamp*).

Another example: 
Instances don't have enough memory available to match the requested *Desired Count*.... events will show something like this:

*"...service myService was unable to place a task because no container instance met all of its requirements. The closest matching container-instance 123456789 has insufficient memory available..."*

Answer (score 4):

To add another data point, I've seen `AWS::ECS::Service` get permanently stuck in `CREATE_IN_PROGRESS` if the ECR docker image is not both a) available from the ECR repo *and* b) pass the health check.

I've tried multiple times to boot an `AWS::ECS::Service` with a valid-image-hash-but-failing-health-check container, then fix the image and do the various "set desired count to zero", "set it back", etc., and nothing AFAICT gets it unstuck.

I eventually have to delete the stack, and start over with an image that *immediately* passes the health check. Then it works fine.

Super flakey.

Comment: This was it for my Django application - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37031749/django-allowed-hosts-ips-range was the underlying issue

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I solved by increasing my allocated memory size for the task definition.

The container(s) you're running must not exceed the available memory on your ECS instance.

Answer (score 0):

To add another possibility, I ran into this issue one time where everything was fine with the template, desired task count = # of running tasks, etc.  It turned out that one of the underlying EC2 instances was stuck near 100% CPU state (but EC2 saw it as "healthy"). It was preventing CloudFormation from validating that particular instance.  I killed the bad EC2 instance, and ECS spun up a truly healthy one.